# How to drag formula in excel while referencing same columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to generate a weighted average and the excel sheet is of the following format

```
Frequency Column1 Column2 ...
F1        C11     C12     ...
F2        C21     C22     ...

WAVG      W1      W2      ...
```

I want to find weighted average. W1 = (F1 * C11 + F2 * C22) / (F1 + F2)

How can I enter formula in W1 cell and drag it across all the columns? I want all the weighted average cells to refer to the same frequency column.

Comment: Use SUMPRODUCT for the numerator and put $ in front of the column letter that you don't want to change as you fill across.

Comment: `$` works as a lock for both/either row/column. `$W1` would mean the column won't change if you drag to the right/left. `W$1` would mean the row number would not change if you drag down/up. `$W$1`would mean neither the column nor the row would change if you drag it anywhere.

Comment: I would suggest a better sample, w2=???, so we can help you. Are there only 2 columns C?